Does the rise time equal the decay time in a DC LR circuit?
The time it takes the voltage to decay from its maximum to zero after the switch is closed is ≈5\$\tau\$. I was wondering, does the same applies during de-energizing, i.e, when the switch is connected to 3? In another words, does the magnetic field takes the same time to collapse as the time it takes to build up?

Reference:
https://ecstudiosystems.com/discover/textbooks/basic-electronics/inductors/series-lr-circuit/

It depends entirely on the schematic (unfortunately unseen in your question).

@Andy aka I've added one

My answer is that they're gonna be the same, because the build-up equation has the same time constant as the decaying equation.

You have the little problem of explaining what position 1 does before you can say that @jack

That is where the switch was before connecting it to 2

@Andyaka so, what is it gonna be Andy?


does the magnetic field takes the same time to collapse as the time it takes to build up?

Answer: Not necessarily.  It depends on the total resistance in the circuit during the two phases you mentioned: build-up, and collapse.  If the resistance is the same during these two phases, then the time-constant is the same, so the time taken for the magnetic field to collapse is the same as the time taken for it to build up.
Let's examine the three states the circuit has:

State 1 when the switch is in position 1.
State 2 when the switch is in position 2.
State 3 when the switch is in position 3.

Let's also assume the switch is ideal, that is: it can change position in zero time, and it has zero resistance across the closed points, and infinite resistance across the open points.
State 1:
The current is zero.  The voltage across R is 0V, and across L is 0V.
State 2:
At t=T1, the switch changes instantaneously from pos 1 to position 2.  Current starts at 0A, and builds up toward a final steady-state value.  Since current is at 0A, the voltage across R is 0V, so all of the supply voltage is impressed across L.
As current builds up, the voltage across R increases while the voltage across L decreases.
At t=T2, let's assume enough time has elapsed that the current in the circuit has reached steady-state, so the voltage across L is zero, the voltage across R is the supply voltage (10V), and the current is:
10V / 10Ω = 1A.
State 3:
At t=T2, the switch changes instantaneously from pos 2 to position 3.  This has changed the circuit: the 10V voltage source has been replaced with a short-circuit (ie: a 0V "source").  We know that the current has not changed (due to L), so the current in the circuit, and the voltage across R have not changed, so by Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, the voltage across R is now impressed upon L.
So what is the change?
the voltage across L has changed instantly from 0V to 10V.
The polarity of the voltage must be such that it will cause the current to decrease - it cannot be the other way, since that violates the golden rule that energy cannot created from nothing.  So the voltage across L will be such that it will cause current to reduce toward 0.  Assuming GND is at Vb negative (yes, please show GND in all schematics), the top of L will be at negative 10V.
So you now have a series R-L circuit with the same initial conditions as you had at State 2, when the switch was moved from pos 1 to pos 2, the only difference being the polarity of the voltage on L.
So the rate of change of current in the circuit will be the same as State 1.  Effectively, the time-constant of the current waveform (hence the magnetic field) during State 3 will be the same as the time-constant of the current waveform during State 2.
When will the waveform (time-constant) be different?
Consider this:  at t=T2, the switch is instantaneously moved back to position 1 instead of position 3.  What happens now?
Since the circuit is now open, and since no current can flow in an open circuit, then we know that the current must go instantly to zero.  But we also know that the inductor current cannot change instantly to zero.  So what happens?
Well, this is the equivalent of "an unstoppable force hitting an immovable object".  If the time for the current to change from 1A to 0A is zero, then the rate of change of current is infinite, meaning the voltage across the inductor is infinite until the current returns to zero, and then everything returns to zero (the current, the voltages, the stored energy, etc).
Of course, in practice, nothing can be infinite, no event takes place in zero time, and we have not explained what happened to the energy in the inductor.
But you can see the main point here: the current waveform is now totally different to State 2;
the time for the magnetic field to collapse is very different to (much shorter than) the time for it to build up.
What has effectively happened is that the resistance that the inductor current must flow through has changed; during build-up phase, it was R1 = 10Ω.  During collapse phase, the resistance is now infinite.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні  You are correct, but it is zero after sufficient time has elapsed.  Which part of my answer is confusing?  Oh, you deleted your comment, ok.

Zero at \$5{\tau}\$? Not really, but at some stage the voltage across the inductor will be close enough to zero, If you say that happens at \$5{\tau}\$ then, ok.
After switching you have the same inductor and series resistor in the circuit all that has changed is the voltage source feeding the circuit is now zero.
(an ideal wire and an ideal 0V source are the same thing)
So given that ideal components are symmetrical it will take the same time to decay that it took to build up, if the measurement is also symmetrical.

Yes, assuming the switch transition from position 2 to position 3 is instantaneous, then the time constant of current decay will be the same as the time constant for the rise of current. Since the voltage across \$R_1\$ is always proportional to that current, the rise and decay of that voltage will also have the same time constant.
\$\tau=\frac{L_1}{R_1}\$ during both phases.
The source and switch arrangement can be modelled as a single source of \$V_1=+10V\$ at time \$t=0\$ and \$V_1=0V\$ at time \$t=1\$, so we can see this behaviour in the following simulation:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here's \$V_1\$:

This is loop current:

Both sections of curve have the same shape, simply flipped vertically with respect to each other. Since \$\tau=\frac{2}{10}=0.2s\$, as expected you see the current cross the 63% (0.63A) and 37% (0.37A) levels exactly 0.2s following a change of \$V_1\$.
